# How to select all the names of elements and their quantities from a XML file?

Tags: php, xml, xmlreader

I have a link to the XML file.

I get it this way:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file('http://example.com');
```

```
SimpleXMLElement {#1631 ▼
  +"@attributes": array:1 [▶]
  +"shop": SimpleXMLElement {#1605 ▼
    +"name": "Site name"
    +"company": "Thomas Munz"
    +"url": "https://example.com"
    +"currencies": SimpleXMLElement {#1606 ▶}
    +"categories": SimpleXMLElement {#1607 ▶}
    +"offers": SimpleXMLElement {#1608 ▼
      +"offer": array:24403 [▶]
    }
  }
}
```

These XML files will change, as will the values in them. I cannot know the names of all elements in advance.
So I want to get an array of all the elements in this XML file with their count.
That is:

```
$array = [
   'attributes' => '1',
   'shop' => '1',
   'name' => '1',
   ...
   'offer' => '24403',
]
```

I really have no idea how to do this :c

Comment: Looks at the docs: https://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.getchildren.php. Mostly the example. Once having the names, get the count with `$xml -> xpath('count(//'.$name.')')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering the question directly as it is currently stated:

> So I want to get an array of all the elements in this XML file with their count.

To count all elements regardless of their nesting level, fetch all elements using the XPath expression `//*`, then count them using a map, e.g.:

```php
$xml = simplexml_load_file('file.xml');

$elements = [];
foreach ($xml->xpath('//*') as $element) {
    $name = $element->getName();
    $elements[$name] = ($elements[$name] ?? 0) + 1;
}

print_r($elements);
```

For the following XML:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<shop>
    <name>Shop name</name>
    <company>Company name</company>
    <url>https://example.com/shop</url>
    <url>https://example.com/shop2</url>
    <url>https://example.com/shop3</url>
    <currencies>
        <currency>
            <name>XXX</name>
        </currency>
        <currency>
            <name>YYY</name>
        </currency>
        <currency>
            <name>ZZZ</name>
        </currency>
    </currencies>
</shop>
```

The PHP code above prints:

```
Array
(
    [shop] => 1
    [name] => 4
    [company] => 1
    [url] => 3
    [currencies] => 1
    [currency] => 3
)
```

---

However, if nesting is important (e.g. the names of the tags may be equal at different levels) or a more sophisticated logic is needed, I'd recommend a recursive function similar to the following:

```php
/**
 * @param array<string, int> $elements
 */
function countElements(SimpleXMLElement $root, array &$elements): void
{
    $elements[$root->getName()] = ($elements[$root->getName()] ?? 0) + 1;

    foreach ($root as $element) {
        $name = $element->getName();

        switch ($name) {
            case 'shop': // no break
            case 'currencies':
                countElements($element, $elements);
                break;
            case 'currency': // no break
            case 'company': // no break
            case 'name': // no break
            case 'url': // no break
                $elements[$name] = ($elements[$name] ?? 0) + 1;
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Another example of a recursive function:

```php
/**
 * Builds an array of element counters and paths.
 *
 * @example
 * <pre>
 *  Array
 *  (
 *      [shop] => Array
 *          (
 *              [count] => 1
 *              [path] => /shop
 *              [name] => Array
 *                  (
 *                      [count] => 1
 *                      [path] => /shop/name
 *                  )
 *  )
 * </pre>
 *
 * @param array<string, array{count: int, path: string}> $elements
 */
function countElements(SimpleXMLElement $root, array &$elements, string $path = '/'): void
{
    $children = $root->children();
    $name = $root->getName();
    $newPath = rtrim($path, '/') . "/$name";

    $elements[$name] = [
        'count' => ($elements[$name]['count'] ?? 0) + 1,
        'path' => $newPath,
    ];
    if (!$children) {
        return;
    }
    $elements[$name] ??= [
        'count' => 1,
        'path' => $newPath,
    ];

    foreach ($children as $child) {
        countElements($child, $elements[$name], $newPath);
    }
}
```

Comment: I am very grateful to you. Your first example is what I need. Don't take it for impudence, but I have one more question))
It would be ideal if I received not only the array name and quantity, but also all the way up to that name. like that:
```
Array
(
    [shop] => [
      'count' => 1,
      'away' =>'shop',
],
    [name] => [
      'count' => 4,
      'away' =>'shop->name',
],
    [currency] => [
      'count' => 3,
      'away' =>'shop->currencies->currency',
],
)
```
How is this possible?

Comment: @Rediska, I've added example of such a function.

Comment: I thank you for your help! I removed some of the code from your example and nothing changed, I think it was unnecessary. I'm embarrassed to ask, but I need to improve the code a little. In order not to litter with comments and to make it clearer, I created a new question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77224791/how-to-convert-a-multi-level-array-to-a-two-level-array-in-php

Comment: @Rediska, Then I might not understand your question. Do you need a **flat** array of the form `[$tagName => ['count' => integer, 'path' => string], ...]`? How would you count the `name` tags if they appear in different levels?

Comment: yes. I need a simple array, but so that the paths are complete.

Comment: @Rediska, Let's assume  there are two `name` elements: `/shop/name` and `/shop/currencies/currency/name`. How would they appear in the output of the function?

Comment: Agree. Then maybe number the array with a number rather than a name? Like this: `$array => [1 => ['name' => $name, 'count' => $count, 'path' => $path], [2 => ['name' => $name, 'count' => $count, 'path' => $path] ...`

Comment: @Rediska, if the key is not so important, you could index elements with the `$newPath`: 1) replace `$elements[$name]` with `$elements[$newPath]` to change the key, 2) replace `countElements($child, $elements[$name], $newPath);` with `countElements($child, $elements, $newPath);` to flatten the array.

Comment: Thank you very much! I am very very grateful to you for your help. This helped =)